# How to server a ".html" at certain URL in a Next.js app?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-router

I have an ".html" file that I need to serve in a certain route in my Next.js app, like this ...

`/pages/customr-route-name/my-html-file.html`

So if I go to my website and type `http://example.com/custom-route-name/my-html-file.html` I can see it

How can I do that in Next.js?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This one requires an API route and a URL rewrite to get working. And the nice thing is, you'll be able to use this pattern for other things too (like if you want to generate an RSS feed or a sitemap.xml).

**NOTE**: You will need to be running Next 9.5 for this to work.

## 0. Move your HTML file (Optional)

Your file doesn't need to be located in the `./pages` dir. Let's put it in `./static` instead. Just replace your these route-file placeholders with your real filename later: `./static/<route>/<file>.html`

## 1. Create the API route

Next lets you create [API routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction) similar to how you would in an old-style host like Express. Any name is fine as long as it's in `./pages/api`. We'll call it `./pages/api/static/<route>/<file>.js`

```js
// import

import fs from 'fs';

// vars

const filename = './static/<route>/<file>.html';

// export

export default async function api(req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8');
  res.write(await fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf-8'));
  res.end();
}
```

## 2. Add a rewrite to `next.config.js`

In Next, [rewrites](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites) work similar to their apache counterparts. They map a url location to a Next `./page`.

```js
// export

module.exports = {
  rewrites: async () => [
    {source: '/<route>/<file>', destination: './pages/api/static/<route>/<file>'},
  ],
};
```

## 3. Run it!

You should be able to test this with a regular `next dev`. Of course, changes to `next.config.js` require you to manually reboot the dev server.

If you look at the Next docs, you'll see you can use wildcards in both the API routes and these redirects, which might help with the direction you're going.

Answer (score 4):

## Update for NextJS Version 11

In your `public` folder you can create a folder structure patterned after the URL you want.

For example:

```
public/custom-path-folder-name/file.html
```

will be served at:

```
http://localhost:3000/custom-path-folder-name/file.html
```

For more information see the [nextjs docs for static file serving](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving)

Comment: How to achieve .html paths for all the pages and not just for static?

For example -
1 - ../parents.html
2 - ../parents/child.html

Comment: This works for NextJS 13 too.